# Control media player on one phone from another

Tags: music-player, remote-control

I recently upgraded by old Wildfire to a Galaxy S2.  For an event I'm running, I'd like to be able to hook the wildfire up to a sound system and play music (that's on the wildfire).  However, I'd also like to control the playback using my S2.  This can be via bluetooth or wi-fi, as I can use the wi-fi hotspot feature if required.

Can anyone suggest any Apps that would allow me to do this?  So far a remote-desktop app is the best I've found, but it's a bit awkward to use.

Comment: I see that desktop Winamp has Android remote control apps - perhaps there's an Android media player with remote controlability?

Answer (score 2):

KODI + KORE 
for those who looking not only streaming but a simple remote control over media player itself (android - to - android)
https://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/494-android-tv-remote-apps.html#s16

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Bluetooth HID implementation for Android

The closest that I know of is [AndroHID](http://code.google.com/p/androhid/)

This turns your smartphone into a bluetooth remote control for any device that supports Bluetooth HID profile.

Comment: Unfortunately that application requires rooting my phone, which I'm not planning to do.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I think rooting is essential because it needs to modify android's bluetooth stack.

Comment: This could be awesome but it could also be dead in the water - looks like the one apk posted is from 2010.

Comment: It still works up to gingerbread and confirmed working on my Xperia Play. For honeycomb and later, you would need to find another app.

Comment: Would this really help since it's just offering a remote keyboard - but he yet needs a screen to see the consequences of his typing...? (Dunno whether this is a req, but it's still a limitation. ;)